# Is apache flink TimerService callback and KeyedProcessFunction.processElement thread safe

Tags: thread-safety, apache-flink

I have a KeyedProcessFunction implementation that override "processElement()" and "onTimer()" methods.
Are they threads safe to each other?

Seems that the onTimer() method is called by a TimerService thead pool. So it looks like to me they could be executed in the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`processElement` and `onTimer` are never executed in parallel.

Prior to Flink 1.10, both methods would be invoked after acquiring the checkpoint lock.

Since Flink 1.10, they are only invoked through the same task thread, so it's even safe to access fields in a non-synchronized fashion (even if using non-managed fields is discouraged to begin with).